# Syntax error of AND in SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am getting some error saying incorrect syntax near AND. I know its because of the bracket

```
SELECT * 
FROM EMP 
WHERE Date BETWEEN ('15-01-2014' AND GETDATE()) AND CODE IN ('CAR', 'CSC', 'HAMTI')
```

I am afraid if I remove the bracket near getdate that AND will have different meaning for the other AND.

Any thoughts on how to write this query with my concern of separating the bracketed code?

Comment: You do not have any ORs, parenthesis are useless, however the GETDATE() might be the issue.

Comment: @plalx: But I do have another AND, so I am afraid

Comment: I applaud your desire to remove the ambiguity from the query, but if all you have ANDs, they'll all have to be true, regardless of what subgroups they're in.

Comment: Your parenthesis are useless (they are **inside** `BETWEEN` construct) and will not make a difference even if placed properly.

Comment: @Xedni: That's exactly my intention, just I didn't write well in English my concern. Thank you :) I will try to understand how these AND conditions everywhere won't affect here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FWIW, Ambiguity in this case doesnt master since you only have two conditions. However, to fix the syntax here, move the first parenthesis back before the `Date`:

```
SELECT * FROM EMP 
WHERE (
         Date BETWEEN '15-01-2014' AND GETDATE()
      )
AND CODE IN ('CAR', 'CSC', 'HAMTI')
```

Comment: Thank you very much Xedni, but may I understand how AND condition everywhere won't affect whether we have bracket or not and why OR condition in a place would affect? I know its silly, is it possible to explain with a very small example? or any links? I can go through please

Comment: 1 OR 0 AND 0 -> 1 AND 0 -> 0  |
(1 OR 0) AND 0 -> 1 AND 0 -> 0  |
1 OR (0 AND 0) -> 1 OR 0 -> 1